# Why are these derivatives equal in Spivak’s Differential Geometry?

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry, differential-forms

This is probably beyond my high-school level competence, but I'm looking at page 112 of Spivak's *A Comprehensive Introduction To Differential Geometry* and wondering how he gets from$$\frac{d\left(f\left(c\left(t\right)\right)\right)}{dt}$$to $$df\left(\frac{dc}{dt}\right).$$

Highlighted below. He's comparing the classical and modern formulations of $df$.

I'm not even sure what the second term means. Is it saying $df$ is a function of $dc/dt$ or is it saying $df$ is multiplied by $dc/dt$? I've fiddled around with the chain rule, but haven't made any progress. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: [Chain rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule)?

Comment: @Jam - How can he do that? Why should $c$ equal $\frac{dc}{dt}$?

Comment: The answer is at the top of page 110, where he answers your question explicitly. (The argument begins at the bottom of page 109.) Note that $df$ is a section of the cotangent bundle that assigns a one-form $df_p$ to each point $p$ of the manifold $M$.

Comment: @symplectomorphic - Yes, I did see that, but I couldn't understand what the $c\ast$ thingy meant on page 109. I guess I was hoping the answer involved some version of the chain rule, but it looks to be more complicated than that.

Comment: @Jam - I left high-school (or the UK equivalent) over forty years ago – I'm a very slow learner :-) This is just a hobby for me; one which I'm not very good at, unfortunately. I'm vaguely familiar with $df\left(p\right)\left(X\right)=X\left(f\right)$ on page 109, but grind to a halt with the next bit involving the$ c\ast$.

Comment: Yes, it’s more complicated than that, if you’re actually trying to understand modern differential geometry... but it’s not *too* complicated... you just have to understand the definition of the differential $df$ and the pushforward $c_*$.

Comment: @Jam, you are misreading and offering unhelpful advice. It’s $c_*$, not $c^*$; it’s not explained on page 107, but in Chapter 3.

Comment: You're right, I'd mixed them up. Apologies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is all clearly explained in the book, but I’ll spell it out again. For Spivak $df$ is a section of the cotangent bundle. That means it is a function from $M$ to $T^*M$, so it assigns to every point $p$ a one-form $df(p)$ that lives in the cotangent space $T^*_pM$ to $M$ at $p$. This one-form $df(p)$ is thus, itself, a linear function from $T_pM$ to $\mathbb{R}$; it operates on a tangent vector to $M$ at $p$ and gives a scalar.

In particular, this one-form $df(p)$ operates on the tangent vector $X\in T_pM$ to give the scalar $X(f)$. Why is $X(f)$ a scalar? This is where you have to understand Chapter 3 on tangent vectors; it is basically the directional derivative of the scalar-valued function $f$ at $p$ taken in the direction of the tangent vector $X$.

To be formal, you can think of $X$ as the tangent vector $c’(t_0)$ to a parametrized curve $c:\mathbb{R}\to M$ with $c(t_0)=p$. But what does “$c’(t_0)$” really mean? It means the pushforward $c_*(d/dt|_{t_0})$ by the map $c$ of the standard tangent vector basis on $\mathbb{R}$. The final step is the important relation at the top of page 80, which tells us how the pushed-forward vector acts; it says (using different letters)

$$(c_*(d/dt|_{t_0}))(f)=d/dt(f\circ c)|_{t_0}$$

Thus, we’ve shown

$$[df(p)](c’(t_0))=d/dt(f\circ c)|_{t_0}$$

If you declutter the notation by dropping the explicit dependence on $t_0$ and thus $p$ as well (as Spivak explicitly says he is doing in the first line of page 110), then this says that the two expressions you’ve highlighted in yellow are equal.

Comment: This is going to give me something to think about. Thanks.

Comment: @Peter4075: you’re welcome. You could accept my answer so that the question is closed.

Comment: Of course. It took me a while just to figure out what the notation meant. It took me another while to understand, more or less, your answer. I was helped by a nice “pushforward” diagram and explanation in Carroll's “General Relativity”, and some more useful stuff in Lee's “Introduction to Smooth Manifolds”.